# IOS NSString get characters before '#"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

for example i have string like this:

NSString *one = B3#This is the first string
NSString *two = 1#This is the second string

How can i get the "B3" and "1" Character only (using objective C)

Thanks..

Comment: Well, for starters, to create a string literal in Objective-C you start with `@"` and end with `"`.  The above statements are meaningless.

Comment: And if you want to know how to, say, separate an NSString into component sections then I'd suggest you read the documentation for NSString.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this is one way to do it:

```
NSRange range = [one rangeOfString:@"#" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *newString = [one substringToIndex:range.location];
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* one = @"B3#";
NSString* two = @"1#";

NSString* result = [one stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
NSString* result_2 = [two stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];

//if you need to marge
NSString* tot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",result,result_2];
```